# horizontally align breadcrumbs - CSS

Tags: css

I am having a hard time aligning the breadcrumbs horizontally.
There is an existing style sheet for the container divs and something in it is preventing the output.

The ul li appear one below the other.

http://jsfiddle.net/y9tyc2cu/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="chatWrapper">
    <div class="chatContainer">
        <div class="chatMsgWrapper">
            <ul id="crumbs">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Main section</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub section</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub sub section</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul#crumbs, ul#crumbs li {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#crumbs {
    height:2.3em;
    border:1px solid #dedede;
}
#crumbs li {
    float:left;
    line-height:2.3em;
    color:#777;
    padding-left:.75em;
}
#crumbs li a {
    /*background:url(/Assets/Images/crumbs.gif) no-repeat right center;*/
    background:gray;
    padding:5px 15px 5px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/y9tyc2cu/4/) is the solution. `float: none;` for each `li` and `display: inline;` for `ul`.

Answer (score 1):

Check here!
if you are a bootstrap user you need
you should have [bootstrap.min.js](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#breadcrumbs)

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#breadcrumbs

`<ul class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>
  <li><a href="#">Library</a> <span class="divider">/</span></li>
  <li class="active">Data</li>
</ul>`

Answer (score 1):

You have two redundant styles for the `li`.

You may **remove** this style:

```
.chatContainer ul li{ 
    float: left; clear: both; margin: 10px 0; 
    width: 100%; padding: 10px; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Also, make the `li` as `display: inline-block` or clear the floats properly:

```
#crumbs li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 2.3em;
    color: #777;
    padding-left: .75em;
}
```

*Your updated fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/y9tyc2cu/2/***

#### Update:

As per your comment, you can't remove or change an existing style. In that case, you need to override the styles which are set in the earlier defined style. Just add these two overrides in `#crumbs li` style, without changing or removing anything elsewhere:

```
width: auto; float: none;
```

So, your complete style now looks like this:L

```
#crumbs li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 2.3em;
    color: #777;
    padding-left: .75em;
    width: auto; 
    float: none;
}
```

*Updated fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/y9tyc2cu/6/***

.

Comment: Thank you. But I cannot remove the existing style. Is there a way, I can add another class for the same and nullify it. I just added `.chatContainer ul li{ }`, but did not work

Answer (score 1):

just add `display:inline` and remove `float: left` from li

example

http://jsfiddle.net/y9tyc2cu/3/