# Make lists horizontal

Tags: html, css

How to make li horizontal? I tried

display: inline

display: float

but none worked.

```
<ul class="pagination" style="display:inline; text-align: center; margin:0;"><li style="display:inline; float: none;"><a href="view_customer_for_manager.php?page=<?php echo $b;?>" style="text-decoration:none; font-size:20px;"><?php echo $b;?></a></li></ul>
```

This is pagination btw

Comment: `display:float;` doesn't exist, you're probably referring to `float:left`. The best nowadays if you don't need to support IE8< is to use `display:inline-block;`, while `display:inline;` should actually do the trick. Now you might have other stuff in your HTML preventing this to work as expected, but that's a good start... that said your example only has 1 `li`  so it's not a good example.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28039444/horizontally-align-breadcrumbs-css/28039581#28039581

Comment: Works after closing a tag: http://jsfiddle.net/1a9detye/

Answer (score 1):

```
li { display: inline; }
```

should work. Maybe you set `ul` to `display:inline;`

Comment: Then you have another problem. `display: inline;` works definitly. Have you tried to debug your CSS using a web-developer plugin for your browser?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `inline-block` elements, for example:

```css
ul {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  text-align: center;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Some content</li>
  <li>Some content</li>
  <li>Some content</li>
  <li>Some content</li>
</ul>

/* If you want the elements to be right next to each other, make sure
   to remove any whitespace between any two elements... */
<ul>
  <li>Some content</li><li>Some content</li><li>Some content</li><li>Some content</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi i managed to make the lists horizontal. However another problem arises. They are not close to each other -> i.imgur.com/FJy7Kws.png how can I close the gap?

Comment: Inline-blocks respect any white space between elements.  If you want left and right edges of the elements to be adjacent to each other, you need to remove any line breaks or spaces as soon above.

Answer (score 1):

`display: float` is erroneous; `float` is its own style property, not a valid value for the `display` style property. This is easily discerned from reading any of the many CSS guides, docs or cheatsheets so your research is lacking there.

Horizontal lists are normally floated either by giving the `li` tags

- `float: left`
- `display: inline-block`

Also make sure the containing `ul` is set to its default `display: block` and is not floated or absolutely positioned - or if it is, ensure it has a fixed width able to accommodate the horizontal list items.

Comment: Hi i managed to make the lists horizontal. However another problem arises. They are not close to each other -> http://i.imgur.com/FJy7Kws.png how can I close the gap?